# CPU/RAM monitoring of one process

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, cpu, monitoring

I know close questions have been asked, but I did not find any answer to this. 
I would like to monitor CPU and RAM of a process I launch, which is executed through several threads. I would like the monitoring to be accurate, at least every 100ms, 10ms would be very nice. So I am looking for something similar to `htop` with the capability of monitoring only one process by extracting its CPU and RAM usage.

If it does not exist, is there a way to monitor and log all processes (like in *htop*) faster ?

Thank you very much !

Etienne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the following command in a loop and see if you can get the update rate you want:

```
ps -p <PID> -mo %cpu %mem >> log.txt
```

Depending on what you mean by "memory", you may be better served by other options, such as `size`, `sz`, `vsz` or `rss`.